# error while creating SSAS cube with SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, ssas, sql-server-ce, olap, analysisservices

I am failing to create a cube in SSAS from a SDF file (SQL CE) as a datasource.
I am assuming it's possible because SQL CE supports OLEDB interface. I am doing this in C# with AMO library.

The error I'm facing during Process of dimensions is the following :

```
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.OperationException
   HResult=0x80131500
   Message=Errors In The High-Level Relational Engine. SqlCeCommand.CommandTimeout does not support non-zero values.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
Errors in the OLAP storage engine : an error occured while processing « dimension » with ID « dimension_test » and name « dimension_test ».
...
  Source=Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.SendExecuteAndReadResponse(ImpactDetailCollection impacts, Boolean expectEmptyResults, Boolean throwIfError)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.AnalysisServicesClient.Process(IMajorObject obj, ProcessType type, IBinding source, ErrorConfiguration errorConfig, WriteBackTableCreation writebackOption, ImpactDetailCollection impact, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, JaXmlSerializer serializer)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Process(IMajorObject obj, ProcessType processType, IBinding source, ErrorConfiguration errorConfig, WriteBackTableCreation writebackOption, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult, Boolean analyzeImpactOnly)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.SendProcess(IMajorObject obj, ProcessType processType, IBinding source, ErrorConfiguration errorConfig, WriteBackTableCreation writebackOption, XmlaWarningCollection warnings, ImpactDetailCollection impactResult, Boolean analyzeImpactOnly)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ProcessableMajorObject.Process(ProcessType processType, ErrorConfiguration errorConfiguration, XmlaWarningCollection warnings)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.ProcessableMajorObject.Process(ProcessType processType)
   at CreateCubeAMO.Program.CreateAndProcessDimensions(Database database, String dataSourceViewName) in C:\Users\...\source\repos\CreateCube\CreateCubeAMO\Program.cs:line 447
```

The datasource is setup as below :

```
DataSource dataSource = database.DataSources.Add(dataSourceName, dataSourceName);
dataSource.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=file.sdf";
dataSource.ManagedProvider = "System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"
```

My understanding of the issue is : by default SqlCommand.CommandTimeout is [30 seconds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), however SqlCeCommand [only accepts 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/compact/sql-server-compact-4.0/96b195wa(v=vs.100)) (for infinity) as a commandtimeout, so the provider of SQL CE does not like the sql command created by default.

The solution would be to set the timeout on the command created by the datasource of the cube, however DataSource only allows to override [timeout of the connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.datasource.timeout?view=analysisservices-dotnet#microsoft-analysisservices-datasource-timeout).

So my questions :
1 - is what I'm trying to do possible ?
2 - is there another way to avoid this issue ? either another provider or perhaps another way to configure this timeout

I've tried setting up global [Server property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/server-properties/general-properties?view=asallproducts-allversions#externalcommandtimeout) "ExternalCommandTimeout" but it didn't work.
I've tried using visual studio and SSMS, same result.
I've tried using the native provider (with connectionstring as below) but I get an internal error :

```
Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID
```

The later looks like an impersonation error, but I've tried default impersonate, service account and personal account with and without password, nothing. Also the SDF file is correct since I can open an OleDbConnection with code below and send queries.

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=file.sdf");
```

Also the whole process works if I use a normal MS SQL Server as datasource, but I want to use the *.sdf.

Comment: Are you using ExecuteNonQuery?  You can use the value returned from the method to catch any exception instead of using a timeout.  The exception is being caught in the library (Provider).  You cannot catch the exception in your code unless the library THROW the exception.  The return value from  ExecuteNonQuery should be positive when successful.

Comment: I have tooling (CLI and libraries) to import a .sdf file into SQL Server, maybe you can use that route? https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox

Comment: @jdweng I’m actually not using an sqlcommand directly, so not calling ExecuteNonQuery. I’m using AMO to create and process a dimension then a cube. I’ve just updated the error with stacktrace which occures within AnalysisServices.Core

Comment: @ErikEJ I’ve actually used your VS extension to browse the sdf, so thank you very much ! My issue however is how to use a .sdf file as relational database to create cube in an analysis database, so technically, to make AMO Classes use SQL CE as datasource. The context is that I am trying to create a serverless solution to create olap cubes : data -> *.sdf -> *.cub . Maybe there is another SQL CE provider that I can try ?

Comment: You can download the source for the library here to debug : https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/releases

Comment: @jdweng Are you suggesting I use another provider from Erik's repo that i will be able to debug ?
I saw there is another EF provider for SQL CE, but I didn't manage to use it (even if I install the nugget, I think the dll needs to be added to the registry so that AMO finds it)

Comment: You do not need to modify registry.  Just treat the library as a child project.  Just add existing and browse to the bin\debug folder.